# What strategy should I apply to get the die?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

[The Di(c)e](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/The_Dice) is unlocked after beating Mom's heart while in the ???-form. I tried again and again, but somehow even fail to make it to Mom. This made me think: There must be some strategies I could apply to raise my chances.

Thoughts so far:

- Since ??? doesn't benefit from Red Hearts, items like Mitre or Mom's Pearl can help a lot
- Devil Room items always cost three Soul Hearts, so it might be wise to visit and skip to raise the odds of an Angel Room appearing
- *Maybe* it's clever to only try to go for the treasure room (and obvious (super)secret rooms) in each floor before heading to the boss. I'd miss out on items but preserve my precious Soul Hearts
- To unlock The Die it's not necessary to start the game as ???, since the Ankh can be used to transform into ??? just before visiting Mom's Heart.

There might be some items that work well together, some items I *have* to find early in the game to even go on with the run or even strategic poop placement.

Is there a single combination of items or a single playpattern that helps preserve life and make it to Mom's Heart?

Comment: Since the game is so random, and the options to achieve the goal are so many, there is really no one good answer.

Comment: But there's also countless decisions to make during a run. What items to grab, which trinkets to keep, what rooms to visit...
I'm not expecting "the one answer" here but useful tips.

Comment: Unfortunately that makes this off-topic for this site. We look for one solid answer, rather than a discussion of strategies.

Comment: Possibly look into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). General discussion may be more useful there.

Comment: To be clear, there could be many strategies to accomplish the goal.  Each answer should fully accomplish the goal, not just be general ideas that may or may not help.  Arqade doesn't work very well with general "tip" type questions, I'm afraid.  If there's a specific part you have trouble with, such as a certain monster keeps killing you, ask us about that.  That's something we can help with.

Comment: [This question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/169544/how-can-i-increase-my-chances-of-getting-cancer/169545#169545), while not directly related, would probably be a good summary of ways you can achieve better luck with this issue. Blue hearts are also more commonly found in the same place (Mystic Slots), but RNG is the biggest issue you will come across.